# js to php format conversion failed

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

This is the working js, I found the logic

http://jqversion.com/#!/XWFtbQb

```
for (var i = 0; i < job.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < jobDetails.length; j++) {
    if (job[i].uId == jobDetails[j].uId) {
      job[i].salary = jobDetails[j];
    }
  }
}

console.log(job);
```

but later I try in php, like this

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $friendstab.length; $i++) {
  for ( $j = 0; $j < $tasks.length; $j++) {
    if ($friendstab[$i]->uId == $tasks[$j]->uId) {
      $friendstab[$i]->tasks = $tasks[$j];

    }
  }
}
      echo json_encode($friendstab);
```

I got an error saying

```
Use of undefined constant length - assumed 'length'
```

am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.length` :

```
$friendstab.length
```

Use `count()` :

```
count($friendstab)
```

[**count()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($friendstab); $i++) {
   for ( $j = 0; $j < count($tasks); $j++) {
      if ($friendstab[$i]->uId == $tasks[$j]->uId) {
         $friendstab[$i]->tasks = $tasks[$j];
      }
   }
}
```

You can also assign subsidiary variables to the `array` or `object` length not to execute `count()` on every iteration ,but only in case when you don't change your collection length in the `array` or `object` :

```
$friendstab_length = count($friendstab);
$tasks_length = count(tasks);
for ($i = 0; $i < $friendstab_length; $i++) {
   for ( $j = 0; $j < $tasks_length; $j++) {
      if ($friendstab[$i]->uId == $tasks[$j]->uId) {
         $friendstab[$i]->tasks = $tasks[$j];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i < count($friendstab); $i++) {} like this?

Comment: @user3522457 : Exactly,I've shown how in my answer.

Comment: Store count separately instead in the iterator. Otherwise the count() will be called on every iteration!!

Answer (score 0):

See [`count()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

Instead of `$friendstab.length` in PHP you have to use `count($friendstab)`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to know the difference between javascript and PHP.

To count a single array variable in PHP use **[count($arrayvariable)](https://www.php.net/count)**

In JS you can use `arrayvariable.length`